# Merging Lists of Different Format into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different lists and an id:

```py
id = 1
timestamps = [1,2,3,4]
values = ['A','B','C','D']
```

What I want to do with them is concatenating them into a pandas DataFrame so that:

| id | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2 | B |
| 1 | 3 | C |
| 1 | 4 | D |

By iterating over a for loop I will produce a new set of two lists and a new ID with each iteration which should then be concatenated to the existing data frame. The pseudocode would look like this:

```
# for each sample in group:
    # do some calculation to create the two lists
    # merge the lists into the data frame, using the ID as index
```

What I tried to do so far is using concatenate like this:

```py
pd.concat([
existing_dataframe, 
pd.DataFrame(
{
    "id": id, 
    "timestamp": timestamps, 
    "value": values}
)])
```

But there seems to be a problem that the ID field and the other lists are of different lengths. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `"id": [id]*len(timestamps) ` ?

Comment: I tried that already and it did not seem to work. But thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
pd.DataFrame(
{ 
    "timestamp": timestamps, 
    "value": values}
).assign(id=id).reindex(columns=["id", "timestamp", "value"])
```

Or:

```
df = \
 pd.DataFrame(
    { 
        "timestamp": timestamps, 
        "value": values}
    )
df.insert(column='id',value=id, loc=0)
```